# jQuery drag and drop if statement don't make any sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone tell me why is this second if statement condition is met.

I checked the length of `.correct` and `.drop` using alert box and the length of `.correct` was 8 and the length of `.drop` was 5. But when I drag an image and drop it then the second if statement was working, it doesn't make sense. Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lawnyan/pcmxwejb/2/.

Here is the code:

```
        $("#car, #boat, #soccer").draggable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
                if (!done) return false;
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                if (($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length)) {

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#win').text(winner + ' ' + 'stars' + ' ' + 'earned' + ' Completion time' + ' ' + counter + ' seconds');
                        alert("the .correct length is " + $(".correct").length);



                } else if ($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#win').text(winner + ' ' + 'stars' + ' ' + 'earned' + ' Completion time' + ' ' + counter + ' seconds');


                } else if ($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#win').text(winner + ' ' + 'star' + ' ' + 'earned' + ' Completion time' + ' ' + counter + ' seconds');



                }

            }
        });





    $("#carDrop").droppable({
        accept: "#car",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.draggable.is("#car")) {
                $(this).addClass("correct");

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {});
            }
        }
    });

    $("#boatDrop").droppable({
        accept: "#boat",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.draggable.is("#boat")) {

                $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
                    done = true;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $("#soccerDrop").droppable({
        accept: "#soccer",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.draggable.is("#soccer")) {

                $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
                    done = true;
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: in your `stop` function all your conditions are exactly the same. Also you have many if statements. Can you clarify which one you mean

Comment: Can you be more specific about which if statement you are talking about? Can you leave only the code relevant to the question (and the rest in the fiddle)?

Comment: all the if (($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length)) {